Spatial selection of intersected entities within a shape does not take the new entity
I'd like to retrieve part of shape A from layer A in relation to the boundary of my layer B. After making an intersection, I end up with a new layer, "intersect_layer".
Using spatial selection with my "intersect_layer" layer and my B layer, with the "is inside" option, intersected shape A is not selected.
I've tried cutting and separating multipolygons, with the same result using QGIS 3.36.1
In the image, I'm trying to recover the purple shapes on top of the green shape. However, since the purple shape at the bottom of the image was originally not just "inside", QGIS doesn't select it for me (whereas now it's an entity in its own).

Conversely, some shapes are not selected because a small piece was on the outside before the intersection.

I suspect that, since the intersection was made with the green shape and I'm trying to select what's inside, the lines are perfectly superimposed and therefore don't count as "inside" (because it is touching the edge is what i'm trying to say).
EDIT answering @Erik : adding "touches" and/or "crosses"
Now QGIS select outside-touching shapes

Edit 2 : testing all the options of "Select by Location"
touch, contain, equal, cross : no selection
Overlap, disjoint, intersect gives me differents results, none that answer (within is stated above).



It could the layer that is cut in a bad way (tried intersect, intersect + cut, intersect + multipart to singleparts) but at this point I do not know what to try.

Try also selecting by  touches and crosses. Inside means is fully inside. For more details check the documentation page: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location

I tried that but now QGIS select outside-touching shapes also. Both results lead me to a manuel review. I've edited the question to add a screenshot.

@MesanGeo: Have you had a look at the contents of the link and maybe tried other options?

I have tried all the options (Edit 2) and tried to cut the file in different ways, but none of them worked. As it is a project for work, I select within and go around the edge to get the last entities.
